# Typescript err: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < evaluating

Tags: angular, typescript1.8

I am working on typescript 1.8/angular2 project. We are building an internal toolkit - a few components like select/dropdown with checkbox, error component, etc. It is currently under a "scripts" folder. I have updated the map under 'systemjs.config.js' to point the "toolkit" location to be under scripts folder. Now I am trying to change the way the components are loaded in client files that want to consume toolkit from ***relative*** to ***non-relative***. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Tools used: Visual studio 2015 update 2. Typescript 1.8

the project layout:

[image]

Code in systemjs.config.js file:

```
var map = {
    'app': 'app', 
    'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
    'moment': 'node_modules/moment/moment.js',
    'InternalToolkit': 'node_modules/Internal.Toolkit'
};

var packages = {
    'app': {
        main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js', meta: { '*.js': { scriptLoad: true } }
    },
    'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'InternalToolkit': {
        main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js', meta: { '*.js': { scriptLoad: true } }
    }
};
```

Now trying to use this toolkit in main.ts file (which is under scripts folder), I write the following code:

```
import {provide, ExceptionHandler} from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {GeneralErrorHandler} from 'Internal.Toolkit/index';
import { AppShell } from './app.shell.component';
```

This compiles fine but when I run it, get the following error in browser console window:

> (index):52 Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <     Evaluating
>   http://localhost:5531/Internal.Toolkit/index  Error loading
>   http://localhost:5531/app/main.js

Note: I tried to add "files" key in my tsconfig.json to point to Internal.toolkit/index.ts but that is throwing 140+ errors. I am unsure if 1.8 can accept "files" key yet. I cannot find 1.9 anywhere -- where I am told there might be a solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have:

```
'InternalToolkit': {
        toolkit: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js', meta: { '*.js': { scriptLoad: true } }
    }
```

Shouldn't `toolkit: 'index.js'` be `main: 'index.js'`?

Comment: true. If changed it ...still same issue. Do you see anything else that I might try? I also fixed it in original posting to avoid confusion.

Comment: You've mapped Internal.Toolkit in SystemJS. The next thing I would change would be: `import { GeneralErrorHandler } from 'InternalToolkit';` Sometimes these errors pop up due to configuration alone.

Comment: I am getting full intellisense there. I can see all other components exposed via toolkit. So I know compiler is seeing it. When I set it to relative path it works fine. That got me wondering what else might be going on that it is not able to see it via non-relative path. I copied all the components to be under node_modules too. I wonder if that's the issue...that I have the same set of files in two different places? Although under the "Scripts" folder, I am not loading it. It sure is some configuration issue..just not sure what I am missing.

Comment: In error it keeps showing --> Evaluating http://localhost:5531/Internal.Toolkit/index ...why it is trying to evaluate from localHost..while I told it to load from node_modules.....is it not trying to load the modules from node_ folder?

Comment: Could it be the way that node or typescript evaluates the tree when looking for imports? I read a great article about this recently. I'll try and find it for you.

Comment: I read this https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039 but i think TS 1.9 is not out yet so I cannot use "Files". Also I am not sure if this would help me...thanks for looking into it. I do agree it's got to do with how TS is evaluating my tree. just not sure where to configure it yet.